# Why do i get '1900-01-01' in my time column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I am working on a Data Frame in `pandas`. I wanted to convert my `time` column into `to_datetime`, I am getting **1900-01-01** before my time.

Some sample data,

```
  Date              hour
01-06-2013      23:00:00
02-06-2013      01:00:00
02-06-2013      21:00:00
02-06-2013      22:00:00
02-06-2013      23:00:00
03-06-2013      01:00:00
03-06-2013      21:00:00
03-06-2013      22:00:00
03-06-2013      23:00:00
04-06-2013      01:00:00
```

This what I tried,

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour'],format ='%H:%M:%S', errors = 'coerce')
```

I am getting like this,

```
print(df['hour'])

0        1900-01-01 23:00:00
1        1900-01-01 01:00:00
2        1900-01-01 21:00:00
3        1900-01-01 00:00:00
```

I do not need 1900-01-01 in my `df`. Why is this happening and how can I get rid of this?

Comment: It would help if you show an example of your original data

Comment: Take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375471/pandas-convert-strings-to-time-without-date it should solve your issue.

Comment: @droravr yes, I looked at it, it, gives the time from it, but, when I use that for later filtering purposes it won't allow me to do

Comment: You can't post 5 dates?

Comment: @droravr this is another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627450/pandas-datetime-formatting I was using, but no definite answer in this!

Comment: Your problem seems solvable, but doesn't contain much information. If the link posted earlier on this comment thread doesnt solve your problem, then you should demonstrate that. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Andrew done, hopefully, that helps. I see there are many threads out there, but nothing helps to get rid of 1900-01-01. As shown above link, it creates a new column with count!

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce').dt.time`?

Comment: @Evert yes, that works to get rid of 1900-01-01 but when I try to filter df by hour, I am getting an error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'` I guess that's a separate question!

Comment: I think that's the actual question you're asking, but it wasn't clear from your previous comment in reply to a linked question. The thing is, if you want a datetime object, you will have to carry along some year-month-day information. If you won't want the 1900 default, combine it with your other column to get the proper datetime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very close, just set the column to time at the end of `to_datetime()`

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df.hour,format ='%H:%M:%S', errors = 'coerce').dt.time

         Date      hour
0  01-06-2013  23:00:00
1  02-06-2013  01:00:00
2  02-06-2013  21:00:00
3  02-06-2013  22:00:00
4  02-06-2013  23:00:00
5  03-06-2013  01:00:00
6  03-06-2013  21:00:00
7  03-06-2013  22:00:00
8  03-06-2013  23:00:00
9  04-06-2013  01:00:00
```